# start os.walk without main directory name

Tags: python

I want to get all the directories from folder. But without printing main directory name from which i am reading.

Means i want to read data from

Folder name (For start the digging in folder) : `Computer/mydata/`

My code :

```
path = "Computer/mydata/"
for i,j,y in os.walk(path):
    name = i
    print(name)
```

Output :

```
Computer/mydata/
Computer/mydata/Abc
Computer/mydata/Bcd
Computer/mydata/Cde
```

I don't want main directory which i use for hunt. Just want to skip that path.
I want to print this :

```
Computer/mydata/Abc
Computer/mydata/Bcd
Computer/mydata/Cde
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a check which sees if the name being printed is same as your `path`

```
for i,j,k in os.walk(path):
    #Only process i if is not the same as path
    if i != path:
        name = i
        print(name)
```

A better approach is to use `os.path` methods like [os.path.normpath](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.normpath) or [os.path.samefile](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.samefile) (Thanks @olinox14) to compare paths if you can get paths with relative components like `Computer/mydata/../mydata/`

For example

```
if os.path.normpath(i) != os.path.normpath(path)
```

or

```
if os.path.samefile(i, path)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just check if this is the same directory. The most safe way of doing this is using [os.path.samefile](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/os.path.html#os.path.samefile):

```
for root, _, _ in os.walk(path):
    if os.path.samefile(root, name ):
        name = i
        print(name)
```